# "Он" после того, как человека только что назвал другой

Tags: грамотная-речь, этикет

Все знают, что в присутствии человека говорить о нём в третьем лице некрасиво. Но я всегда считал, что в ответ на то, что его называет другой человек, ты можешь уже сказать про него "он" или "она", чтобы не повторять как попугай то же имя. Прав я или нет?

Возьмём пример:

*— Ой, почему Лёня весь в крови?!

— Да **он** вовсе не в крови, тётя Галь, это **он** шелковицы наелся!*

Comment: А что не так? Если ты говоришь о каком -то человеке, неважно, рядом с тобой он или нет, только в третьем лице можно сказать.  Никак не иначе. А красиво- не красиво — вопрос этики, а не русского языка.

Comment: Нет, Сержик, это языковой вопрос. Не третьим лицом называют присутствующего, а только по имени. Третье лицо - просторечие.

Comment: Ну хорошо, Галин, так как в моём примере надо ответить? Неужели заменить "его" на "Лёню" в обоих случаях непременно?

Comment: Избегая повторов имени, зачем повторять местоимение? Первое — явно лишнее.

Comment: @shampar: не согласен с вами. Первое местоимение придаёт выразительности фразе!

Comment: Можно пожертвовать другим, заодно убрав **это**: «*Да он вовсе не в крови, тётя Галь, — шелковицы наелся»*.

Comment: Да можно, но непонятно, надо ли к этому стремиться. Мой вопрос вообще не про повтор местоимения, а про него как таковое.

Answer (score 2):

1. Я бы записала диалог так:

***— Ой, почему Лёня весь в крови?!***

***— Да  вовсе не в крови, тётя Галь, просто шелковицы наелся!***

2. То есть здесь использован самый простой способ, а именно **пропуск местоимения** "он" (об этом уже говорилось в комментариях).
3. Этикет в данном случае **предельно строг**: нельзя говорит "он" в присутствии лица, при этом неважно, что имя уже было названо.

Вот мнение **филолога:**

Но сегодня мне кажется, что проблемы современной речевой культуры связаны и с другим моментом общения — тем, что называется **фактор третьего лица.**

Действие этого фактора проявляется в том, что общающиеся (в первую очередь это относится к устной речи, то есть к говорящим) должны принимать во внимание того/тех, кто непосредственно в общении не участвует, но **присутствует** при этом — находится **в одном пространстве.**

Этот учёт присутствующих заметнее всего, когда они выступают **героями высказываний**. В этих случаях о них нельзя говорить ОНИ (ОН, ОНА). Это невежливо. **Надо называть человека** по имени или имени-отчеству, обозначить его по отношению к вам — мой сосед, моя жена, мой сын; или по его роли в данной ситуации — наш гость, мой научный руководитель…

Если же содержание речи третьих лиц **не касается, то их присутствие всё равно учитывается.**

4. Таким образом, в каждой ситуации надо искать какое-то решение, например:

*Да  вовсе не в крови, тётя Галь, просто наш  любитель  экзотики шелковицы наелся!*

Или что-то в этом роде, если хотите красиво и интересно выразить свою мысль.

Comment: Спасибо, Sharon! Жалко, если действительно ничего не остаётся, как избегать называть человека в таких случаях, не нравится мне это.

Comment: Можно сказать: Да вовсе не в крови, тётя Галь, просто Ленька шелковицы наелся! Всё не чистый повтор, слух не так напрягает. Лишь бы имена рядом не стояли и часто не повторялись. А вот "он" говорить нельзя.

Comment: Также отмечено, что особо строгие требования предъявляются, если лицо участвует в беседе (тогда местоимение "он"  особенно заметно). В противном случае отклонения от правила вроде бы допускаются, но нормированными они все равно  не будут.

Comment: А мне казалось, что даже если не участвует, но слышит, то нехорошо говорить "он", интуиция это подсказывает, но думал, что если уже назвали имя, то уже другое дело. Ан нет!.. :(

Comment: Sharon, здравствуйте! Ну вот почему тогда все говорят "он" в присутствии человека?! И в старых советских фильмах тоже. Можете мне объяснить?

Comment: @Артём Луговой
Привет, Артем. Это сообщение до меня не дошло, надо для  старых тем почту писать, наверное. Честно говоря, я не знаю почему.  Мне сейчас кажется, что без разницы,  что говорить: Ленька или он. Все равно это будет ТРЕТЬЕ лицо.  Вероятно, мы УСЛОВНО считаем, что Ленька нас как бы не слышит и не присутствует при разговоре, даже если он здесь. У меня такая версия. А вообще надо смотреть конкретные примеры.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Вот как, не доходит!.. Интересно вы сейчас рассудили, мне нравится. :) Сейчас собачку написал, а она исчезла)))

Comment: @Артём Луговой А сейчас я увидела сообщение, вероятно, система отслеживает новую активность. Я тоже вчера еще подумала о вашей теме. Если Леня совсем рядом, почему не спрашивают у него (Леня, ты почему весь в крови). И если Леня не знает, что испачкался, и плечами пожимает, то его как бы и нет, за него отвечают друзья. И даже если ответил (не знаю), то нужно его тоже видеть со СТОРОНЫ, чтобы догадаться о причине (тогда он опять условно отсутствует).  Мы интуитивно чувствуем ситуацию и выбираем подходящий вариант, поэтому не стоит полностью доверять правилам, где на все случаи одно решение.

Comment: Да не новая активность! Я же говорю, собачку поставил с вашим именем, но её не видно просто.  Сейчас тоже поставил, хотя можно было в качестве эксперимента не ставить. Последняя фраза просто золотая у вас, полностью поддерживаю!

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, слова в диалоге во многом зависят от персонажей и самой ситуации. Если в вашем диалоге по сюжету отвечает ребенок или друг, родственник, то слово "он" вместо имени воспринимается гармонично. Если, наоборот, произносить все время имя, будет выглядеть официально и немного странно. Можно представить ситуацию: Леня стоит, молчит и не знает, что ответить. Его друг, посмелее, быстро пытается объяснить в чем дело. И потом, например, говорит: "Правда же, Леня? Ну скажи, ведь так?". Леня, соглашаясь, качает головой и улыбается.